# High-level Overview of the StackOverflow API

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, api

I'm waiting for an invite to the Beta, but I'm curious. What does the API provide access to at this current time? I'm just looking for a high level overview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I have access, I may as well answer my own question. The api is read only at this stage, but it is quite extensive. You could almost use it to build a complete read-only version of the StackOverflow site. You can access not only questions and answers, but other information such as tags and users ect. Many of the retrieval options allow you to choose the sort order (pretty much the same options available on the site). The biggest missing feature at the moment is probably search.

Answer (score 3):

Here's your invitation.  Oh, and your high-level overview:

[**Stackoverflow API Private Beta Starts**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/stack-overflow-api-private-beta-starts/)